# Webdriver Loss of Control

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Sometimes the connection to the selenium driver is lost due to an error occurring.
How to regain control of webdriver without reloading the domain being tested?
I'm doing tests using C #
Thanks so much for the answers!

Comment: Are you getting an exception? What is the exception and stack trace? Does the error happen randomly or does it consistently fail at a certain point?

Comment: Thanks.
Is there a way to take back control of Webdriver?

Comment: I have no idea. I need you to answer the questions I posted in my previous comment.

Comment: @Mike try providing more detail in your question like a code example or describing a little bit more the scenario. As Greg Burghardt asked it will be useful to know if you get any exception or when *precisely* are you experiencing this connection lost.